# CakePHP Foreach doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach, controller

I'm new to CakePHP and I'm currently trying to get all the rows in my table "genres" and "themes" to fill some multiple checkboxes but when I try the foreach, I always get the errors below :

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: genres [APP/View/Pages/register.ctp, line 88]
>
> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Pages/register.ctp, line 88]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined variable: themes [APP/View/Pages/register.ctp, line 98]
>
> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Pages/register.ctp, line 98]

However I set 'genres' and 'themes' in my GenresController and ThemesController but I keep getting this error. Here's my code :

**register.ctp**

```
<div id='stream'>
            <?php
            foreach ($genres as $genre):
                echo $this->Form->checkbox('Genre.0.libelle', array(
                    'value' => $genre['Genre']['id'],
                    'name' => $genre['Genre']['libelle']
                ));
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id='webserie'>
            <?php
            foreach ($themes as $theme):
                echo $this->Form->checkbox('Theme.0.libelle', array(
                    'value' => $theme['Theme']['id'],
                    'name' => $theme['Theme']['libelle']
                ));
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </div>
```

**GenresController :**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

/**
 * CakePHP GenresController
 * @author Sen
 */
class GenresController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

        $this->set('genres', $this->Genre->find('all'));
    }

}
```

**ThemesController :**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

/**
 * CakePHP ThemesController
 * @author Sen
 */
class ThemesController extends AppController {

    public function index($id) {
        $this->set('themes', $this->Theme->find('all'));
    }

}
```

I've tried to set an array to $genres just like that but it says that my GenresController's index isn't defined :

```
$genres = array();
$genres[0]['libelle'] = "Lamb";
$genres[1]['libelle'] = "Ham";
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have defined `index` actions for both the controller. But using those variables in `register,ctp`. You should fetch all of them in `register` of the controller you are calling.

Comment: you need to add `$this->set('genres', $this->Genre->find('all'));  $this->set('themes', $this->Theme->find('all'));` in your AppController `beforefilter()`function. Load model there too. `remove index()` code from both controller and create a `register()` in any controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class PagesController extends AppController {
     public $uses = Array('Genre');

     public function register() {
         $this->set('genres', $this->Genre->find('all'));
     }
}
```

Add above code to register action in pages controller and dont forget to use the modal

Answer (score 0):

```
class GenresController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Genre','Theme');

    public function index() {
         $this->render('register');
         $this->set('genres', $this->Genre->find('all'));
         $this->set('themes', $this->Theme->find('all'));
    }

}
```